# How to solve Googlecloudmessaging cannot be resolved to a type error in Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create GCM Push Notification.
I followed the same steps described in below link:
http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

After installing google-play-services using sdk manager, google-play-services folder is created but inside it there is no folder of lib. And I got the error of 'googlecloudmessaging cannot be resolved to a type'. How to resolve it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#play-services

Try to ignore use of google-play-services-libs jar file, always import google-play-services-libs project as a module.